# NetBeans charset problem. Linux -> Windows

Tags: netbeans, character-encoding

I have problem with charset in my NetBeans on Windows when I open files, which were editting in NB on Linux by my coworkers.

I guess it should be unicode in both.
What I should to do to resolve this problem?
I can find proper option.

Answer (score 2):

I use frensh and changed the netbeans encoding to Iso-8859-1 and it worked for me. 
tried UTF-8 before didn't do it
my symptoms were as follows:
- a website hosted on linux and developped by another dev
- downloaded on my windows 8 , netbeans 8.0 beta or 8.1
- when opening a file for the first type it was saying "cannot option safely..." if chose Yes all my frensh special chars were messed up
-Hicham

Answer (score 0):

right-click on Project -> Properties -> Sources -> Encoding
for maven project, put project.build.sourceEncoding in pom->project->properties

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with Eclipse because of mixed Windows and Linux developers. If you use Java you have 3 options:

- change to Unicode charset. Though we couldn't do that with Eclipse on Windows, maybe it works out for you. Linux should be usually on Unicode already.
- change to Iso-8859-1 on Linux, seems to be compatible with CP1252
- use the tool native2ascii to change non-ASCII-characters in strings to their explicit unicode representation (IMO this is the most robust solution, though it's Java only I guess)

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to solve this is by a terminal command

```
$  sudo sh  netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh
```